# Azure Event Grid / Function / ngrok

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I'm trying to follow the instructions [Local Testing with ngrok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid#local-testing-with-ngrok)

I have my event gird running and my function running in VS locally using the C# example.  However, when I try to subscribe to my event using the endpoint

```
https://xxxx.ngrok.io/admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig?functionName=EventGridTrigger
```

My local ngrok console shows:

```
POST /admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig 404 Not Found
```

Function code in VS:

```
  [FunctionName("EventGridTrigger")]
    public static void Run([EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info(eventGridEvent.Data.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there is an error in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid#local-testing-with-ngrok) published by Microsoft.  The ngrok example is for functions v1.  If you are using functions v2 then this is the URL required to trigger the function:

```
https://{subdomain}.ngrok.io/runtime/webhooks/EventGridExtensionConfig?functionName={functionName}
```

See the issue logged [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9812)

Comment: Sorry about the trouble. Just added put out a PR to our docs repo to make sure the V2 endpoint is also captured.

Comment: Years later, this accepted answer didn't work for me while Sushruth's did by using a different URL format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52488798/4967486.

Answer (score 6):

based on your description, the following attribute must be used:

```
[FunctionName("EventGridTrigger")]
```

you can test it with the Postman:

```
http://localhost:7071/admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig?functionName=EventGridTrigger
```

note, that the following header must be added:

```
Aeg-Event-Type:Notification
```

**Update:**

the following is my working function via ngrok and custom topic created by VS 2017 Version 15.7.5:

```
// This is the default URL for triggering event grid function in the local environment.
// http://localhost:7071/admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig?functionName={functionname} 
// Aeg-Event-Type:Notification

using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace FunctionApp10
{
    public static class Function2
    {
        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static void Run([EventGridTrigger]JObject eventGridEvent, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info(eventGridEvent.ToString(Formatting.Indented));
        }
    }
}
```

and the dependencies:

[image]

**Update2:**

the function for version 2 generated by VS from the EventGridTrigger template is the following:

```
// Default URL for triggering event grid function in the local environment.
// http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/EventGridExtensionConfig?functionName={functionname}
// Aeg-Event-Type:Notification

using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp11
{
    public static class Function2
    {
        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static void Run([EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation(eventGridEvent.Data.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

and the dependencies:

[image]

*Note for localhost:7071 postman test:*

the payload must be as an array of the events

Comment: Edited question to show my function.,  It is decorated as you suggest.  If I POST to http://localhost:7071/ I get "Your Azure function is up and running".  However, using the URL we both think should work (with the header you suggest) fails to return anything.

Comment: This works using function SDK v1.  I was using v2 - see my solution above

Comment: creating an EventGridTrigger function by VS, the generated code from the template shows in the comment line the url local address (localhost:7071). Everything is working for me, I can run via ngrok and from localhost:7071.  So, based on this comment and AF version, the destination endpointUrl can be properly populated for local debugging.

Answer (score 1):

For function 2.x the url is https://{subdomain}.ngrok.io/runtime/webhooks/eventgrid?functionName={functionName}.

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid).