# EventGrid subscription binding works via ngrok to a local machine, not with a function in Azure

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I have an Azure Function App that I can create an EventGrid subscription to when it's hosted on a development machine via ngrok, but exactly the same function, when published to Azure, will not accept a subscription.

The error is "The attempt to validate the provided endpoint <> failed".

I have considered obvious things like the length of urls, but this does not seem to be the cause. The only difference between the two urls is the host, as in the host url of the function app, and the ngrok generated host. I have tried both using the portal and CLI to create subscriptions with the same result.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue using the Azure CLI in powershell. For me the answer was essentially Roman Kiss's comment: Escape the the endpoint URL, because it contains an & symbol.

eg, changing this:

```
  -endPoint "https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid?FunctionName=xxxx&code=xxxxx"
```

to this:

```
  -endPoint "https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid?functionName=xxxx""&""code=xxxx"
```

The reason it worked using ngrok was because the ngrok endpoint (pointing to a local development function host) doesn't require the &code=xxxx part.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer unless Roman Kiss adds an answer.

Comment: This was the answer. Strangely it's not - or wasn't - in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

there are two kinds of azure function triggers what can be used for event grid subscriber, such as:

1. HttpTrigger

   ```
   endpointUrl format = https://{functionApp}.azurewebsites.net/api/{functionName}?code={functionKey}
   ```

Note, that the HttpTrigger function has a responsibility for validation of the event grid message. See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/receive-events#endpoint-validation).

2. EventGridTrigger

   ```
   endpointUrl format = https://{functionApp}.azurewebsites.net/admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig?functionName={functionName}&code={_masterKey}
   ```

It looks like, your endpoint doesn't include the url query string.

Comment: Hi Roman, I'm using the latter, though without the _masterkey. The critical thing is not that it doesn't work - it does - it's that it works via ngrok and not with the same Function App running in Azure. If I had screwed up the url, neither would work.

Comment: note, that the ngrok tunnel doesn't require any query parameter in the url, also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51675648/azure-event-grid-function-ngrok

Comment: This is a little unclear. ngrok is just a tunnel, so the destination Azure function needs the functionname query parameter to know which method to call, so surely both routes require query parameters. Or are you talking about some other parameter?

Comment: sorry, it's my mistake, for ngrok or local test: the HttpTrigger doesn't require any query parameter (the function is a part of the url path), but in the case of EventGridTrigger there is a mandatory query parameter such as the functionName. Note, that the url path is depended from the version of the AF, for v1 the path is /admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig, for version v2 is  /runtime/webhooks/EventGridExtensionConfig. In this case, there is a built-in an event message validator and forwarder to the EventGridTrigger function based on the query parameter functionName.

Comment: more details can be found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid#local-testing-with-ngrok

Comment: btw. are you using Azure CLI to update a subscription destination endpoint? Note, that the value should be wrapped by double quotation marks to avoid a conflict character & in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to include the code parameter when accessing the EventGrid subscriber in the cloud, rather than on a development machine. Details are here. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid#create-a-subscription

The text of the above, which is all the documentation there seems to be, does not state that this is specifically required.